# How to make background http request periodically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am working on android app. It should be able to get data from server every second in background (like WhatsApp and other messanger does). It should ring alarm even if mobile is silent if particular data is received from server.
Any ideas how can i code this in android studio.

Comment: try [google cloud messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/) to set up Google Cloud Message and customized ringtone. Android will send data to the app whenever there are new messages.